# Compare two arrays integer arrays in python by each element

Tags: python, arrays

I need to compare two integer arrays in python by each element. The second array consist of elements in the first array **but not always every one**. I need to check whether an element in the first array is present in the second array. All elements in first and second array are **unique**. I need a binary string that consists of Boolean values (0/1) for each element in the first array which was absent/present in the second array.

For example: my first array `arr1=[1,2,3]` and my second array `arr2=[2]`

I need the result as `"010"`. The first `"0"` means that the first element in `arr1` (which is 1) is not present in `arr2`.
The second `"1"` means that the second element in `arr1` (which is 2) is present in `arr2`. The third `"0"` means that the third element in `arr1` (which is 3) is not present in `arr2`.

How to do it in python?

Comment: please consider adding your attempted code to your post, as is, you will not get much help

Comment: `array.array` or `numpy.array` or python `list`? Please post your actual code. `arr1[1,2,3]` is not valid python.

Comment: @timgeb i am new to python and i doesnt try any codes. I want to know how this to do in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your arrays are simple list, then you can simply use list comprehension to accomplish this:

```
output = "".join( [ "1" if x in arr2 else "0" for x in arr1] )
```

If you are ok with a list of integers you can simplify it to:

```
 output = [1 if x in arr2 else 0 for x in arr1]
```

Comment: No need for the quadratic complexity here. Use a set of the list you call `__contains__` on.

Comment: True that, for his example it won't change much though ;)